# Cordova - Change default webview to support AdX

Tags: android, cordova, google-ad-manager

I have a client requirement to use Google AdX inside the cordova application.

It seems like corodova default webview does not support this currently?

Is it possible to change the default webview to Chrome Custom tab?

Any suggestions implementing Google AdX inside cordova app greatly appreciated.

Comment: For mobile apps, I believe you would be looking into Google Admob instead, I believe it is part of Google Ads. There also is a plugin for that.

Comment: Thank you Eric, will do test Google Admob and plugin.